# How to recover the removed state after Git rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase

[Here](http://git-scm.com/book/mk/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%9A%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE-Git-Rebasing) in "The Basic Rebase" example (Fig.3-27) it is shown how the `experiment` branch is rebased with `master` branche. As a result (Fig. 3-29) from `C3` state patch is taken, applied that patch on `C4` and `C3'` us created. Then, finally, `C3` as a state is removed. My question is how to recover `C3` state?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "recovering" `C3`?  `C3` indeed will still exist in your repo until it's automatically garbage collected by Git, and you can use `git reflog` (and other Git commands) to find it, but what do you want to do with it once you've found it?

Comment: @guido that would work, but is unnecessary, as the original `C3` is still pointing to `C2`.

Comment: If `C3` was checked out when you performed the rebase, the symbolic reference `ORIG_HEAD` will refer to the original `C3` directly after the rebase.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `git fsck --lost-found`, you'll get a list of commits that are not reachable by tags or branches. The commits lost in the rebase will be on the list. Find the most recent one, and `git checkout` the corresponding hash. You can then tag it, make a branch, or whatever you like.

[See here for a working example](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/01/17/restoring-lost-commits.html).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to get back to the commit state `C3`, do

```
git reflog
```

search for commit `C3` {line from reflog - `e3eee5a HEAD@{4}: commit: C3`}, then

```
git reset e3eee5a
```

You will now be back to state `C3`, **keeping changes** introduced by `C4`

To remove changes introduced by `C4`, user `reset --hard <commit>`

Comment: While `git reset <commit>` will work, if you're not using `--hard`, you'll leave behind a (probably very) dirty working copy. Though maybe that's what the Original Poster wants...not enough info yet to tell.

Comment: @Cupcake, you are right. My answer stopped there as OPs goal was reached. Added newline to answer so OP has a choice :p